# railsアプリがherokuにデプロイできません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler

#### 実現したいこと

- herokuにrailsアプリをデプロイしたい

#### 環境

- Ruby 2.4.0
- Ruby on Rails 5.1.6
- bundler 2.0.1
- Javascriptランタイム: node.js

#### 現在の状況

vagrant環境ではrailsサーバの起動、ブラウザでの表示まで確認しています

#### 問題・エラーメッセージ

- `git push heroku master`でデプロイに失敗します
- heroku buildpacksがnode.jsに設定されてしまいます

buildpacksを指定しないでcreate後にgit push heroku master場合のエラーコード

```
2019-10-03T21:33:48.503244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 28886`
2019-10-03T21:33:50.666191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-03T21:33:50.708819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-03T21:33:50.712474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-03T21:33:50.586012+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /app/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
2019-10-03T21:33:50.586039+00:00 app[web.1]: To update to the lastest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
2019-10-03T21:33:50.586041+00:00 app[web.1]: To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
2019-10-03T21:33:50.586047+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `bin_path'
2019-10-03T21:33:50.586049+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

buildpacksをheroku/rubyを指定してcreate後にgit push heroku masterした場合のエラーコード

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to your-appname
```

#### 試したこと

- bundlerのバージョンを2.0.1に変更しGemfile.lockを再生成

https://qiita.com/haru52/items/c2e062f6e1c7d4ecfe49

- Gemfileが小文字のgemfileになっていたので修正

https://qiita.com/leavescomic1/items/ca938f4637b125da5bcf

- buildpacksをheroku/rubyを指定してデプロイ

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby

https://dhtakeuti.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/11/142638

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

なかなか解決できないのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/215264

Answer (score 0):

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2` してみるとどうでしょうか？

Comment: 試してみましたがプッシュできていないようです


```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: ! Push rejected to your-appname.
remote:
```

`heroku create`時にbuildpacksを指定するのとcreate時には`heroku buildpacks:set`でbuildpacksを追加するのは動作的には同じなのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、後から `buldpacks:set` すれば良いです。リポジトリのルートディレクトリに Gemfile は存在していますか？

Comment: ルートディレクトリのGemfileは存在しています
もう一度試してみます

Comment: お、heroku-buildpack-bundler2 を見に行ったら、公式がもうサポート済みって書いてありますね。 https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1563 を見ると、Gemfile.lock の `BUNDLED WITH` に従って自動で bundler のバージョンを判断するようですが、ルートディレクトリに Gemfile.lock も存在していて `BUNDLED WITH` にバージョンが書いてありますか？

Comment: - `heroku create`時にheroku/rubyを指定してbuildpack2を追加
- `heroku/create`にbuildpackを指定せずに後でbuildpack2を追加

どちらも同じエラーでした

Gemfile.lockのWITH BUNDLEは2.0.1で`bundle -v`も2.0.1です

Comment: app ディレクトリにゴミの Gemfile.lock が存在していませんか？

Comment: `ls -a`
assets  channels  controllers  helpers  jobs  mailers  models  views

Gemfile.lockはありませんでした

Comment: あ、問題を完全に勘違いしていました、ごめんなさい。node.js と両方の buildpack を使いたいって話でしたね。では `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby` した後に `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs` してみたらどうでしょう？

Comment: node.jsのbuildpackを使いたい訳ではないのですが、buildpackを指定せずにpushした際に勝手にnode.jsのbuildpackが選択されてしまうんです。

以前cloud9を使いRailsチュートリアルを進めていた際にはbuildpackを指定しなくても自動でheroku/rubyが選択されエラー無くデプロイできました。

ちなみにnode.jsはJavaScriptランタイムで必要との事だったので使用しました。

Comment: なるほど、ちなみに Gemfile を小文字から大文字にした後や、Gemfile.lock を更新した後は commit していますか？(git status は clean ですか？)

Comment: `git status`はcleanです。
nodejsとruby両方のbuildpackを入れて試してみましたがダメでした。
buildpackの順番でエラーが出る事もあるらしいので順番を入れ替えてみましたがやはりダメです。
buildpackを自動で選択できていない事からアプリ自体に原因があるという事なのでしょうか？

Comment: お手上げですね！手元にないと調査は難しいですが、公式リファレンスと伺った情報を照らし合わせて雑にまとめると、まずデフォルトで node.js が選択されるのは、ルートディレクトリの Gemfile が読めていない可能性が高いです。 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure で、`buildpacks:set` で heroku/ruby を選択しても失敗するのは Gemfile.lock の `BUNDLED WITH` が見えていない可能性が高いのではないかと推測しました。 https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1563 確かに、まずは node.js が選択される状態が事の発端の異常なので、そちらから解決した方が良さそうですね。

Comment: 分かりました！
再度最初からやり直してみます！
お手上げだという事が分かっただけでも精神的に楽になりました！
変な時間に回答してくださりありがとうございました！